# Can debug on Android tablet with one user account but not another

Tags: android, adb

I'm developing an Android app with in-app billing and am following [these instructions](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial#Adding_In-app_Billing_Test_Accounts). As described under Adding In-app Billing Test Accounts, I've added a second account to my Nexus 7 tablet. I can debug using my original account just fine, but this new account doesn't work. When I try to run

```
adb –d install /path/to/release/apkfile.apk
```

in a Terminal window on my Mac, I get, "error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device." When I check the device by running

```
adb devices
```

it shows as unauthorized when I'm using this new account. I've seen suggestions in other posts to disable debugging and then kill and restart the adb server, but this test account doesn't have Developer options enabled and I'm not able to enable them for some reason. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Popups such as the USB debugging RSA fingerprint acceptance dialog only appear on the main account. Try

1. Opening your second account
2. Plugging your tablet into the USB port on your computer
3. Without unplugging the USB port, go back to your primary account
4. Accept the RSA fingerprint dialog
5. Switch back to your second account

At that point, your device should appear as authorized even when you are on your second account.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid this doesn't work. When I follow your instructions, my device still shows up as unauthorized when my second account is the one logged in. I'm able to install the apk using the adb -d install command for my primary account, but not my second account.